# difference between "run |" and multiple runs in github actions

Tags: github-actions

what is the difference between

```
steps:
  - name: npm install, build, and test
    run: |
      npm ci
      npm run build --if-present
      npm test
```

and

```
steps:
  - name: npm install, build, and test
  - run: npm ci
  - run: npm run build --if-present
  - run: npm test
```

in github actions? 
I tried to read the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps) on steps but it does not mention anything like that

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Difference is that first example is executed as single script with three commands, and second example is executed as three different one-line scripts (side note: second example is invalid, as you use step with `name` without `run`, i'll ignore that line).

---

Let's assume for a second that `npm` does not create any output when running. In first example, if one of commands fails, it might be a problem to identify which one - you have only one step marked as failed. In second example, you'll know exactly where the problem is, as each command is its own step.

---

Let's assume for a second that `npm` needs to be run in specific subdirectory. We need to remember that each steps always starts in workspace directory / repo's root directory, so we need enter directory where our stuff is first.

```
- run: |
       cd my/directory
       npm ci
       npm run build --if-present
       npm test
```

```
- run: npm ci
  working-directory: my/directory
- run: npm run build --if-present
  working-directory: my/directory
- run: npm test
  working-directory: my/directory
```

OR

```
- run: cd my/directory && npm ci
- run: cd my/directory && npm run build --if-present
- run: cd my/directory && npm test
```

---

Let's assume for a second `npm test` needs to be run only on `push` event, but workflow is configured to run `on: [push, pull_request]`

```
- run:   |
         npm ci
         npm run build --if-present
         if [ "${{ github.event_name }}" == "push" ]; then
            npm test
         fi
  shell: bash
```

```
- run: npm ci
- run: npm run build --if-present
- run: npm test
  if:  github.event_name == 'push'
```

Under *Actions* tab, when processing `pull_request` event, second example will be displayed as...

```
- Run npm ci
- Run npm run build...
- Run npm test <-- this one will be grayed out
```

...and you need only a quick look to see that `npm test` step is skipped. In first example you'll have to expand step first and inspect log to notice any difference.

---

And so on, and so on, there's dozens of scenarios when it's easier/better to use *all-in-one* step, and as much scenarios when *command-by-command* steps are the way to go; it's up to you to decide which one fits you best.

At the end of the day, both examples do exactly same thing, after all. But if anything goes wrong along the way, picking one way to run commands over another (which also changes how they're displayed) can make a difference how long it gonna take to prepare a fix.

Comment: trying to use multiple `run: ` commands I get this error: `
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/deploy.yml (Line: 26, Col: 9): 'run' is already defined .github/workflows/deploy.yml (Line: 27, Col: 9): 'run' is already defined
`

Answer (score 2):

**run: |** is executed as a single-line script with the commands you mentioned.

**Example:**

[image]

**run:** Each command will be executed as a one-line script.